# C# How do I fix this error error with my MessageBoxButtons/Icons

Tags: c#, messagebox

Designing a registration form, and I get this error when adding in MessageBoxButtons and MessageBoxIcon.
The error is "argument 2: cannot convert 'system.windows.forms.Messageboxicon' to 'string'.
The piece of code where the error is, is this: **

> MessageBox.Show("You have successfully registered your account",
>   MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxButtons.OK);

**
As well as here:

> MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all of the boxes correctly",
>   MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxButtons.OK);

When I remove the Messageboxbutton/icon, there is no error.
Here is what I have got:

```
        {
        MyConnections.insert.CommandText = "INSERT Customer(EmailAddress,Firstname,Surname,Password)VALUES('" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtFirst.Text + "','" + txtSur.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "')";
        MyConnections.insert.Connection = MyConnections.Customer;
        MyConnections.Customer.Open();
        MyConnections.insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnections.Customer.Close();

        if (txtFirst.Text.Length > 0 && txtSur.Text.Length > 0 && txtEmail.Text.Length > 0 && txtPassword.Text.Length > 0 && txtConfirmPass.Text.Length > 0)


        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully registered your account", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxButtons.OK);


        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all of the boxes correctly", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxButtons.OK);


        }
```

Comment: Did you check the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.7.2) link on MessageBox.Show? Perhaps if you added a "title" to the call your error may go away magically.

Answer (score 0):

Here you did have the right order and you forgot to add a caption

```
MessageBox.Show("You have successfully registered your account","Your caption goes here", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Hope this helps.